# How to clip in drawRect when drawing (and clipping) based upon CGMutablePathRefs

Tags: ios, core-graphics

In my custom control I have defined a few CGMutablePathRefs with the needed lines and arcs to draw my control; one draws the overall fill shape and others provide specular highlights.  I have also defined two CGMutablePathRefs which contain the paths needed as clipping masks for the active and inactive state of the control.

What I'm struggling with is applying the clipping paths.  I have previously used clipping paths for applying gradients to an image, but those drawing commands were of the CGContext... variety, not the CGPath... variety.

For testing purposes I have removed the specular highlight drawing aspects, just trying to get a large path clipped to a smaller path.  This is what I had been testing with:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, inactiveClip); 
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, frontFace);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

}
```

By putting the clipping command before any drawing, I thought I was saying to CoreGraphics, "Here's the region you should actually draw into."

Alas, nothing is drawn.

So assuming I had that ordering backwards I tried:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, frontFace);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, inactiveClip); 
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

}
```

This was to say to CoreGraphics, "Okay before you actually color bits, check them against this clipping region."

Alas, nothing is clipped.

Since it is the case that my clipping path uses some of the same points and control points, in the same order, as the fill path, I have also replaced the call to CGContextClip with a call to CGContextEOClip to see if I was really struggling with the even-odd rule, but that doesn't seem to have had any visual affect.

I don't really know if I needed to bracket the CGContextAddPath call with CGContextBeginPath/CGContextClosePath calls, but what I was trying to do was minimize the differences between Apple's example code and my code.  In theirs they do their CGContext... drawing calls between begin/close calls so I was too.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You definitely need to clip before drawing. Are you sure `inactiveClip` is valid? If you try filling it, does it appear where you think it should be?

Comment: Also: You shouldn't need the `CGContextBeginPath` and `CGContextClosePath`; try taking them out.  They're probably harmless but you never know.  (Your context shouldn't have an active path when `-drawRect:` is called, and `CGContextClip` automatically closes the path if it's open -- which it shouldn't be, anyway, if you constructed it correctly.)

Comment: Thank you for asking if it was a valid path.  "Of course it is" was my initial thought, based on the fact that my paths were constructed from instance variables, and I used the same instance variables to build the different paths.  However, I initialized my new clipping path PRIOR to initializing those instance variables.  Grr.